# CSS class selectors not having same behavior as id selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have constructed a mock-up of a hierarchical menu system, where the main menu (#moduleMenu1) has a sub-menu (#moduleMenu2), and they both share a CSS class. When I use ID selectors on the menus, all is well (http://jsfiddle.net/stamminator/pwnuymd2/1). However, when I switch to using a class selector, which would be much more elegant (especially if I add a third hierarchy to the menus), the selectors are being overwritten (http://jsfiddle.net/stamminator/pwnuymd2/).

I suppose I can use `!important` on every property in my styles, but assuming I'll need to have a page which overwrites those styles on an as-needed basis at some point, this isn't a great solution either. Is there a third option besides id selectors or `!important` that is available?

I'm not sure if this is related, but I've noticed a second problem as well. When I have the HTML files open locally and do a selector in Chrome's JavaScript console on their shared class, I would expect to get back both elements. Instead, I only get back one.

```
//what I typed into the console:
$(".moduleMenu");

//my result:
<div id="moduleMenu1" class="moduleMenu">
    <div>
        <a href="">Proposal</a>
        <a href="">Browse</a>
        <a href="">Financial</a>
        <a href="">Documents</a>
    </div>
</div>

//where's #moduleMenu2? They both have the same CSS class
```

Here is a link so you can download the files and run it in your own debugger if you'd like: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9F7FCE5CCA52BABF!33812&authkey=!ANi0Ivf0BbmVbGk&ithint=file%2czip.

The JavaScript console issue is a non-issue I suppose, but I figured I'd mention it in case it's related. Any help I can get in getting my CSS working properly would be much appreciated!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: As to your second question, your assumption is correct. Please provide a demo.

Comment: @Quentin is my question missing any of those? I included everything.

Comment: @JacobStamm — There is no CSS in the question. There is no element with `id=moduleMenu2` in the question.

Comment: Please refer to any of the 3 links I provided, two of which are ready-to-go demos. You will find `<div id="moduleMenu2"></div>` in all three.

Comment: Neither of the answers address the real issue: in the second fiddle, you have an error in the selector for the `a` elements; there's a comma behind the last one. Remove the comma and everything works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/pwnuymd2/4/ Closing because of simple typographical error.

Comment: @JacobStamm — Links to content hosted on third party sites is not the same as "in the question itself"

Comment: @Quentin it's something that is only apparent when debugging, so unless you've got a debugger that works in plain text, your comments contribute nothing.

Comment: @JacobStamm — Stackoverflow does have the ability to give live demos in questions, but even if that wasn't the case, it misses the point. The question depends on a third party source to be understandable. If that source ever goes away, the question breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID selectors are of higher importance than class selectors. You should almost never use IDs in CSS. Change your ID selectors to class selectors (even if they're unique) and be happy.

```
<div id="moduleMenu1" class="moduleMenu moduleMenu1">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwnuymd2/2/)

Of course, some of your listed selectors can now be combined.

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/pwnuymd2/3/)**

Comment: @Quentin, I believe he's saying that my use of ID's is unnecessary, as I could simply use classes with the names `moduleMenu`, `moduleMenu1`, and `moduleMenu2`. In retrospect, this seems so obvious! Thanks @isherwood, I think this will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by isherwood, ID selectors take priority over class selectors. This is due to CSS specificity, which is the way CSS determines which rules are applied to an element.

The simplest way to explain CSS specificity is:
!important > inline > ID > class > element > universal & inherited

For a slightly more in-depth explanation, CSS specificity is stored as four separate integers. When no styles are applied to an element (or only universal and inherited rules are applied), the values for that element are 0,0,0,0.

- The first value represents inline styles
- The second value represents ID style rules
- The third value represents class or attribute style rules
- The fourth value represents tag style rules

1,0,0,0 overrides 0,1,0,0: an inline style will always override an ID style rule. Likewise, an ID will always override a class. However, 0,1,1,0 overrides 0,1,0,0, so a class and an ID in a rule will override the ID rule.

With the exception of some older browsers that roll over values after 255, there is no number of classes that can override an ID: the only way to override an ID style rule is with an ID, inline styles, or the !important flag.

Comment: Thanks for this guide. @isherwood already helped me with this issue in particular, but I will keep this bookmarked, as your answer is great for reference :)